# How does one Revert all of the Commits from a Child Branch of a Branch in GIT based upon the Commit Descriptions?

Tags: git, powershell

Supposing I have a branch called `Sprint 1` and I have derived a branch from it called `Feature 1` and another called `Feature 2`.  I've switched working on `Feature 1` and `Feature 2` intermittently, merged `Feature 2` back into `Sprint 1`, then merged `Feature 1` back into `Sprint 1`.  I now want to undo the merge of `Feature 1` into `Sprint 1`  along with the hundreds of commits that came from `Feature 1`.

Since I've been informed that GIT cannot keep track of which branch a commit came from, all of the descriptions on my commits from `Feature 1` are prefixed with `Feature-1` and all of the descriptions of my commits from `Feature 2` are prefixed with `Feature-2`.  How do I revert the 100s of commits from `Feature 1` now in `Sprint 1` jumbled in amoungst the `Feature 2` commits?

I'll use Powershell to drive GIT in a revert loop if I have to!  I just need a command to get a list of `Feature-1` commit refs to run through if this is the approach I need to take.

Comment: You might consider reverting the merge itself rather than the commits brought by the merge. Reverting hundreds of commits will likely be a very long, tedious and error-prone process. Take a look at the [`-m`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#Documentation/git-revert.txt--mparent-number) flag for revert.

Comment: Won't that mean I'll have a load of orphaned files from `Feature 1` still in my `Sprint 1` branch?

Comment: Yes @MattArnold, You have revert the merge completely and then do a cleansing. Once cleansing is done, you have to a remerge from scratch and that is not a tedious process. So, Romain's suggestion is the most recommended one at this moment.

Comment: You've just reminded me that merging that branch in was a very tedious process and one which I would rather not have to go through again!  Now I'm a dilemma: take Romain's approach and later get questions about the existence of files which are not used or revert everything then have to write a 2nd Powershell loop to only revert the reversions when merging anything new from `Feature 1` back in.

Comment: @RomainValeri What number do I need to give -m to get it to keep the current branch (`Sprint 1`) and throw out `Feature 1`?  Apparently it needs: "the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline" - what is the mainline and how do I find out the number of a branch?